# DBsetup with GWT

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, maven, gwt

Im working on a Project with `GWT(Eclipse)`, commitment via `SVN` and we got a Database working with `MySQL`.

We decided to test our Database with `DBsetup` which is based on `Maven`.
And I´m the responsible Person for the Database Tests.

I decided to clear my question here,

MY questions:

- where do I have to put the `DBsetup.jar` in our Project folders?
- Do I need to open a new `Maven` Project in our GWT Source folders?
  or is it enough to keep the maven Project in my Local folders?

And Thanks for Answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use maven then I'd suggest you start with maven then use m2e to integrate with eclipse. DBSetup is in maven central so you can just manage it like any dependency.

I think the norm would be to have a folder structure like:

```
myproject
--- myproject-database
--- myproject-model
--- myproject-gwt-client
```

NB the "myproject-" prefix is annoying but makes life a lot easier in eclipse etc and maven artifacts.

Have you looked at the GWT maven plugin for compiling and running tests? It makes life a lot easier.

It took me a long time to come to terms with maven but once you give in and do things the maven way then lots of tools etc will just work "as if by magic" as you are using the maven conventions.